# Date formatter produces strange output

Tags: java, date-format

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        List<String> strd = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Date> date = new ArrayList<>();
        strd.add("Sun May 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009");
        strd.add("Wed Jun 11 03:17:40 UTC 2008");
        strd.add("Mon May 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009");
        strd.add("Mon Jun 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009");
        strd.add("Sun Jun 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009");
        List<Character> letters = new ArrayList<>();
        char letter;
        for (letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++) {
            letters.add(letter);
        }
        List<String> dateToChar = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int j = 0; j < strd.size(); j++) {
            try {
                String strDate = strd.get(j);
                // String strDate = "Mon May 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009";
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
                Date dateStr = formatter.parse(strDate);
                String formattedDate = formatter.format(dateStr);
                System.out.println("Date is ==>" + formattedDate);
                Date date1 = formatter.parse(formattedDate);
                date.add(date1);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                System.err.print(e);
            }
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < date.size(); k++) {
            for (int h = 1; h < date.size(); h++) {
                if (k != h && k < h) {
                    if (date.get(k).equals(date.get(h))) {
                        System.out.println("Equal dates");                        
                    } else {

                        System.out.println("Not Equal dates");
                    }
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I do the parsing, the output is:

```
Date is ==>Mon May 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009
Date is ==>Wed Jun 11 03:17:40 UTC 2008
Date is ==>Mon May 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009
Date is ==>Thu Jun 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009
Date is ==>Thu Jun 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009
Not Equal dates
Equal dates
Not Equal dates
Not Equal dates
Not Equal dates
Not Equal dates
Not Equal dates
Not Equal dates
Not Equal dates
Equal dates
```

Why? I cannot understand the reason! The last dates are wrong, but only the last ones. If I change the date, for example, the output is wrong again.

Comment: @LordTorgamus it's probably because the cast from `ArrayList<?>` to `List<Date>`. Check my answer.

Comment: Ah, I suspected it was a Java version thing. Thanks for the note, @alkar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results in your print out look correct to me as the Day of Week is not being used by the date parser.  If the only difference between two of the strings is the day of the week, then they will parse to the same date value.

First pass thru loop:

```
"Sun May 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009" vs "Wed Jun 11 03:17:40 UTC 2008" == not equal month
"Sun May 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009" vs "Mon May 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009" == equal (DoW ignored)
"Sun May 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009" vs "Mon Jun 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009" == not equal month
"Sun May 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009" vs "Sun Jun 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009" == not equal month
```

Second pass thru loop:

```
"Wed Jun 11 03:17:40 UTC 2008" vs "Mon May 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009" == not equal month
"Wed Jun 11 03:17:40 UTC 2008" vs "Mon Jun 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009" == not equal year
"Wed Jun 11 03:17:40 UTC 2008" vs "Sun Jun 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009" == not equal year
```

Third pass thru loop:

```
"Mon May 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009" vs "Mon Jun 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009" == not equal month
"Mon May 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009" vs "Sun Jun 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009" == not equal month
```

Fourth and final pass thru loop:

```
"Mon Jun 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009" vs "Sun Jun 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009" == equal (DoW ignored)
```

Comment: Even if i change the month, when i parse and print the result, the date of the week is not different. If i want to use the day as a difference, what can i do?

Comment: The loop checks only the `date` `List`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are misled by your own input:

```
strd.add("Sun May 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009");
strd.add("Mon May 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009");
```

May 11th 2009 was Monday. As far as I know (but can't find any source for this) day of week is overrided by day of month. So you sunday is changed after parsing into monday.

Then everything looks correct. During your loop, the only place where dates are equal is for:

```
k=0; h=2;
Date is ==>Mon May 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009
```

And in loop where:

```
k=3; h=4; 
Date is ==>Thu Jun 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009
```

I don't know if you did this on purpose, but one date has year **2008**:

```
Date is ==>Wed Jun 11 03:17:40 UTC 2008
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the wrong dates, it's because the name of the day you used is not a valid day. Take the last one for example `Sun Jun 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009`. Look it up in a calendar, it was a `Thu` that date. The parser knows this and outputs the correct day.

Now the loop, it has no error if you follow it step by step, you'll see that the output is correct since it checks the `List` `date` with itself.

Finally, if you're using Java 6 or earlier, there are some issues with your casts in the code:

```
List<Date> date = new ArrayList<>();
```

is not really valid and should instead be

```
List<Date> date = new ArrayList<Date>();
```

(thanks @Reimeus for pointing out this is valid in Java 7)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the date `List` objects. This is type inference introduced in Java 7.

Comment: Oh, is it? I'm sorry I've been using 6 en masse. Will fix my answer.

Comment: @LefterisBab do not forget to tick the correct answer :)